# Hi, my 2D game character teleport a little bit higher, and then he come down very slow, like a leaf when i press the jump button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQIHZ.png)

If i keep presing the button it keeps going up. When i remove the script for moving left pr right it works good but when i add it , i have this problem.
here is my code

`
{
Rigidbody2D rb;

```
float dirX;
float jumpForce = 300f;
float moveSpeed = 5f;







void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
void Update()
{
    dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 10, 0);

    

    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        DoJump();
}  
    void DoJump()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Force);
    } 
    
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea only these changes have to be done

rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 10, rb.velocity.y);

rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Force);

Comment: i made the changes, but now it wont even jump

Comment: gimme some time to think over  it

Answer (score 0):

rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * 10, rb.velocity.y);

rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Force);

Comment: i made the changes, but now it wont even jump

Comment: maybe remove "if (rb.velocity.y == 0)" and use something different

Comment: Why are these two answers the exact same with the exact same comment on it